# i have problem when tryin to sort data in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, sorting, dart, google-cloud-firestore

have problem when trying to sort data from firebase

```
 Flexible(
                child: StreamBuilder(
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('comments')
                        .where('id', isEqualTo: id)
                        .orderBy('time', descending: true)
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      }
```

the code above is working when i comment `orderBy()` or comment `where` but its not working together when i try the two function it keep reloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to handle the errors to understand what happens:

```
Flexible(
  child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('comments')
      .where('id', isEqualTo: id)
      .orderBy('time', descending: true)
      .snapshots()
      .handleError((error) => print(error.toString(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,
      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
```

For now, just adding the `handleError(onError)` should help.

Comment: description=The query requires an index. You can create it here: idk what does this mean

Comment: Well, it means just that. Firestore usually auto-manages the required indexes but for some combined queries, you need to generate the corresponding index. Just follow the link and create the index.